# A 9-letter word

Tags: word

> 1,2,3 - do it once, then again and again and you get a dance.
>   8,9,7,6 - makes you unique and the same
>   3,4,6 or 3,5,6 - a drink

What is the word?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's

> **Challenge**

1, 2, 3:

> cha; three times makes [the Cha-cha-cha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha-cha-cha_(dance)).

8, 9, 7, 6:

> gene; the particular combination of [genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene) makes us all human (the same), but since everyone has different alleles everyone is unique.

3, 4, 6 or 3, 5, 6:

> Ale; self-explanatory, [ale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ale) is a popular type of beer

Comment: beat me to it !

Comment: pfff...I feel dumb now. I was looking for 2 different drinks.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for:

> challenge.

It was given up for me by your first clue, which is

> cha-cha-cha.

An interesting subset of the list of 9 letters word beginning like this are

> {"chaffinch", "chagrined", "chainsaws", "chairlift", "chalkiest",
>  "challenge", "chambered", "chameleon", "chamomile", "champagne",
>  "champions", "chanciest", "chandlers", "channeled", "chanteuse",
>  "chantings", "chantries", "chaparral", "chapattis", "chapbooks",
>  "chaperons", "chaplains", "charabanc", "character", "charbroil",
>  "charcoals", "chariness", "charities", "charlatan", "charmless",
>  "chartered", "charterer", "chartists", "charwoman", "charwomen",
>  "chastened", "chastised", "chastiser", "chastises", "chasubles",
>  "chatlines", "chattered", "chatterer", "chattiest", "chauffeur"}

From where it was easy to spot

> ale.

Then it was a simple check to see that

> gene

actually fits.

Comment: Just beaten to it by Wu, +1 for getting it though

Comment: Yes, I guess it took me a while to write up my answer. Time for me to earning some points towards a sportsmanship badge!

Comment: This is a dupe of the other answer.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος your constructive comment was noted. Thank you.

Comment: @Matsmath Sarcasm aside, I checked the posting timestamp of the two answers, and yours was 8 seconds later, but, I get it, internet connections can be slow.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος And not everyone works on answers on the site itself. If you have another window open, you aren't looking at the page, so you don't notice the small grey banner saying that there's a new answer that might not even have appeared yet.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes That's why I didn't flag.